# Class 'JString' Not Found

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

The below error is what I get when I load my site. Can anyone let me know why it's happening. Is it plugin issue or not?

> Fatal error: Class 'JString' not found in
>   /home/issyoga/public_html/plugins/content/emailcloak.php on line 67

Answer (score 1):

`JString` should be loaded by the autoloader. Check if your Joomla installation has the file `libraries/joomla/string/string.php` and that the file is not corrupt and does not have permission issues. Not sure what caused this in the first place (it might be a corrupt upload or it might be that the file was compromised).

Alternatively, you can just disable the Email Cloaking plugin (although I think you will experience the same problem in another plugin unless you fix the root problem).

A good idea would be to re-install the Joomla core through cPanel - just make sure you delete the `images`, the `installation`, and the `templates` folders from the zip file before extracting it, and make sure you backup your site first (filesystem + database).